# How to flatten a mesh around an object

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I would like to flatten a terrain mesh I generated using a racetrack mesh so the terrain appears flatter around the area where the track runs through, I've tried a few different modifiers for this and the closest one to what I needed was the cast modifier, unfortunately it only deforms with the 3 primitive shapes around the transform of the track and not the mesh itself. Is there a plausible way of doing this or would I have to sculpt the terrain manually?

The red circles in the picture below illustrate where I'd need the terrain to flatten out for the track to run through.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is your track generated using a curve modifier? I'm thinking you could make a "V" shaped boolean object extending upward to cut out a valley in the terrain.

Comment: that's a good idea I'll give that a shot and let you know how it turns out, thanks.